# How to send post values from a route to another route name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `laravel` and I want to send some values from a route name to another route name.

first route:

```
/api/register
```

I'm using curl:

```
    $fields = array (
        'stuf' => 'stuf',
    );

    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );

    $headers = array (
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $url = '127.0.0.1:8000/api/emamian';
    echo "started -0---";
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8000);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT ,3000);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    var_dump($response);
    echo '------';
    var_dump($err);
    curl_close($ch);
   return;
```

second route:

```
Route::post('/emamian',function() {
    echo "masoud";
    return;
});
```

I'm using localhost with port 8000.
but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: You mean something like [subrequests](https://github.com/myerscode/laravel-sub-request)?

Comment: Do not edit questions after there is an answer.  You can provide updates, but your edit changed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute URLs always need to start with a protocol.

```
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/emamian';
```

Comment: I try it but when I send a request in Postman it remains in the loading status and doesn't get response

Comment: Hmm.  Might be an issue with built in web server not being able to handle a request to itself due to synchronous processing.  I wouldn't recommend doing a CURL request like this to your own API anyways.  If you find yourself needing to call another controller, it likely means you need to extract logic to a  model or service class.